# Angular 2 - send email with mailgun using HTTP Post

Tags: angular, mailgun

Im trying to send emails from my angular 2 application with mailgun but I'm having problems with authorization and only getting 403 responses.

This is what I've got so far

```
 var authHeader = new Headers();
    authHeader.append('Authorization','API_KEY');
        var url="https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY_MAILGUN_DOMAIN.mailgun.org/messages";
    var mail = {
      from : "text",
      to : "text",
      subject : "text"
      text : "text"
    };
   this._http.post(url, message, {headers:authHeader});
```

Does anyone know how to attach my api key to successfully authorize?

UPDATE:

```
 var headers = new Headers(); 
    headers.append("Authorization": "Basic "+btoa("api:key-API_KEY")
```

I needed to provide the API key with btoa encoding.

Answer (score 4):

according to [mailgun doc](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#base-url) you can attach it like this way

```
https://api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0@api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/log
```

**BUT**

If you do that with Angular 2 then your api key will be public (because angular 2 is front end script framework) and anyone can get and see and use your api key.

You should send email from back-end (php,nodejs, rails, etc)

EDIT:
I just did a test with my sandbox account, without any problem, I sent like this:

```
https://api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7296.mailgun.org/messages
```

Remember if you are not using sandbox domain, then you have to configure DNS records and verify the domain

Comment: I know that I should do it from a backend but in this case it does not really matter. This will not be used in production. Ive tried to authorize the way you suggested but i does not work. Do you got any other suggestions?

Comment: I updated the answer, I did a test, and it worked.  if you are not using sandbox domain, you have to configure DNS records and verify the domain

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you anyway for your time, mate! I've updated my post too.